# Matching column elements using the closest values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multiple-columns

I have a Matrix A of 1000 rows and 2 columns.

```
A = [0.0325 5.6 ; 0.0367 7.6 ; 0.0391 8.1 ; 0.0404 9.7; etc.]
```

I want to find the matching element in the 2nd column for a given value that is not necessarily in the first column.

For instance, for a given value 0.0371, I would want a value of 7.6 since it corresponds to the 2nd column value of the element that is the closest from my input 0.0371 (0.0367).

For 0.0393, I want 8.1, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the difference between each of the elements and your desired value, then find the index of the minimum. The value you want will be at the index in column 2.

```
[~,idx] = min(abs(A(:,1)-testval));
desiredval = A(idx,2);
```

Comment: Fun fact:  If you are just using `val` as a dummy variable, you can replace it with `~`. For example: `[~,idx] = min(abs(A(:,1)-testval));`

Comment: I think that only applies to versions above... R2012a, I want to say, but it could be before that. Nonetheless, good point, answer edited!